# How can I prevent UNPIVOT from being transformed into UNION ALL?

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, union, unpivot

I have a somewhat complex Oracle query which is taking about half an hour to complete. If I take the slow part of the query and run it separately it finishes in a few seconds. Here's is a screenshot of the SQL Monitor report for the isolated query:

[image: ok plan]

Here is the same logic when run as part of the full query:

[image: bad plan]

The colors correspond to the same tables in both screenshots. For the slow query, Oracle is doing a `MERGE JOIN` between two tables that do not have an equality condition in the `JOIN`. As a result of that, about 150 million intermediate rows are unnecessarily processed.

I am able to work around this problem with query hints or rewrites, but I want to understand as much of the root cause as I can so that I can avoid this problem in the future and possibly submit a bug report to Oracle. Every time I get the bad plan the `UNPIVOT` in the query text is transformed into a `UNION ALL` in the plan. To further investigate I would like to prevent that query transformation from happening. I have been unable to find a name for this transformation. I also have not been able to find a query hint or underscore parameter that will prevent it. I'm testing on a development server so anything goes.

Is there anything that I can do to prevent the query transformation of the `UNPIVOT` to `UNION ALL`? I am on Oracle 12.1.0.2.

I am not able to share the query, table names, or data for IP reasons. I was not able to come up with a simple reproduction. With that said, it's unclear to me why that information is needed to answer the question. [Here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=607819d8c7f7068ca2dbb05f4a1f3deb) is an example of an UNPIVOT query along with the same query implemented as UNION ALL.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following Oracle optimizer hint:

```
NO_EXPAND
```

This hint disables OR-expansion. OR-expansion transforms combined OR-conditions or IN-lists in the `where` clause into a compound query with the `union all`.

We don't have your SQL so this is a guess but seems to a viable option.

As a second option, since you are in a development environment, you can try the Oracle optimizer hint:

```
NO_QUERY_TRANSFORMATION
```

but this hint disables *all* query transformations that the optimizer *can* perform other than transformations that the optimizer *always* can apply.